# itertools not defined when used inside module

Tags: python, function, module, anaconda, python-itertools

I save my custom functions in a separate module that I can call when I need to.  One of my new functions uses itertools, but I keep getting a name error.

```
NameError: name 'itertools' is not defined
```

It's really weird.  I can import itertools in the console just fine, but when I call my function, I get a name error.  Usually I can use functions from other libraries (pandas, sklearn, etc.) inside a custom function just fine as long as I import the library first.

BUT if I import itertools in the console, copy and paste my function into the console, and then call the function, it works fine.

It's making me crazy, but I'm thinking maybe I'm just not understanding the rules of modules or something.

here's the function i'm using in the module.  it's simply copy and pasted from one of the sklearn examples:

```
import itertools    
def plot_confusion_matrix(cm, classes,
                              normalize=False,
                              title='Confusion matrix',
                              cmap=plt.cm.Blues):
        import itertools
        plt.imshow(cm, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cmap)
        plt.title(title)
        plt.colorbar()
        tick_marks = np.arange(len(classes))
        plt.xticks(tick_marks, classes, rotation=45)
        plt.yticks(tick_marks, classes)

        if normalize:
            cm = cm.astype('float') / cm.sum(axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]
            print("Normalized confusion matrix")
        else:
            print('Confusion matrix, without normalization')

        print(cm)

        thresh = cm.max() / 2.
        for i, j in itertools.product(range(cm.shape[0]), range(cm.shape[1])):
            plt.text(j, i, cm[i, j],
                     horizontalalignment="center",
                     color="white" if cm[i, j] > thresh else "black")

        plt.tight_layout()
        plt.ylabel('True label')
        plt.xlabel('Predicted label')
```

I tried importing it inside the function, inside the module, and inside the file where I am calling it - all with no luck.  If I import it in the console its fine.  Even after it's been imported in the console, if I run it inside the file I'm working on again, it gives the same error.

Comment: Import `itertools` in the same module were your function lives

Comment: You need to import itertools in the file that's using it. If you import that file, it has its own namespace.

Comment: I tried importing it in my module, but it still produced an error.
I also tried importing it in the file that's using it - still an error.

Comment: If you tried importing itertools to both of the modules and still got the error, provide a minimal working example code for us to look at

Comment: Your code example *doesn't* import itertools. Make sure your example is a [MCVE].

Comment: I took it out. Updated in original post

Comment: You should try importing with a lowercase `i`, `import` ... And it's OK to import outside the function, it just has to be in the same file.

Comment: Still nothing. This is too weird.

Comment: So are you positive that when you call the above function (exactly that!), you get the above NameError? Are you sure it's coming from that function, and not somewhere else?

Answer (score 15):

It works now.

IMPORTANT LESSON:
If you edit a module, you must close and reopen spyder/ipython/whatever.  Simply resetting the kernel is not sufficient.  Stupid of me, I know, but maybe maybe this answer will save someone time.

Comment: I find it unlikely that anybody who could benefit from this will *find* it, but let's hope for the best:) I'm glad you figured it out eventually.

Answer (score 1):

You just change
`for i, j in itertools.product(range(cm.shape[0]), range(cm.shape[1])):`

To:

`for i in range (cm.shape[0]):
    for j in range (cm.shape[1]):`

Comment: That is not the point in OP question. The point was why `itertools`was not loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can first use *from itertools import product*, then change itertools.product into simply *product*. That should work.